# Finding matches in two bags

Tags: algorithm

This was one of the interview questions, and I was wondering if I did it right, and want to know if my solution is the most efficient one. O(n log n)

> Given a bag of nuts and a bag of bolts, each having a different size within a bag but exactly one match in the other bag, give a fast algorithm to find all matches.

Since there is always a match between 2 bags, I said there will be same number of nuts and same number of bolts. Let the number be `n`.

I would first sort components in each bag each component's weight, and it is possible to do that because they all have different size within a bag. Using merge sort, it will have O(n log n) time complexity.

Next, it would be just easy process of matching each component in 2 bags from lightest to heaviest.

I want to know if this is the right solution, and also if there is any other interesting way to solve this problem.

Comment: Yup, looks like you nailed it.

Answer (score 10):

There is a solution to this problem in O(nlgn) that works even if you can't compare two nuts or two bolts directly. That is without using a scale, or if the differences in weight are too small to observe.

It works by applying a small variation of randomised quicksort as follows:

1. Pick a random bolt b.
2. Compare bolt b with all the nuts, partitioning the nuts into those of size less than b and greater than b.
3. Now we must also partition the bolts into two halves as well and we can't compare bolt to bolt. But now we know what is the matching nut n to b. So we compare n to all the bolts, partitioning them into those of size less than n and greater than n.
4. The rest of the problem follows directly from randomised quicksort by applying the same steps to the lessThan and greaterThan partitions of nuts and bolts.

Comment: nLog(n) is the best and average case, insertion sort is worse case o(n^2)

Answer (score 4):

The standard solution is to put the bag of nuts into a hash (or HashMap, or dictionary, or whatever your language of choice calls it), and then walk the other bag using hash lookups to find the matches.

Average performance of this algorithm with be `O(n)`, with better constants than your sort/binary search variation.

Comment: That looks better, assuming you can find a hash function that will work for both nuts and bolts. I mean, `match(bolt,nut) -> boolean` is trivial - O(1) - but which property would you use for hashing such that `f(nut) == g(bolt) for all nuts and bolts`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have no exact measurements of size, and you can only see if something is too large, too small, or exactly right by trying, this needs the extra step of how you are sorting -- which is probably by taking a random nut, comparing with each bolt and sorting into smaller, bigger piles, and then taking a bolt and sorting the nuts with that (a modified quicksort... keep in mind you'll have to deal with the problem of how to choose a nut or bolt to compare to when the piles get smaller as to make sure you're using a reasonable pivot).

Since the problem doesn't tell you that the nuts and bolts are labeled with sizes, or that you have some way of measuring the nuts and bolts' sizes, it would be difficult to use a hash table to solve this, or even a regular comparison sort.

Comment: However, if the bolts vary in more than one scale (for instance, girth, thread height and thread spacing), you can't easily partition them using a pivot... I'm guessing in the general case, all things considered, you can't do it in less than `O(n^2)`

Comment: (P.S. before someone points it out, I know this extrapolates from the OP specs; I still think this solution in the best one for the case given)

Comment: @mgibsonbr: Re: "if the bolts vary in more than one scale (for instance, girth, thread height and thread spacing), you can't easily partition them using a pivot": That's not true. Each of those "scales" is readily comparable, so you can order all the two bolts by using a lexicographic ordering (first compare girths; if girths are equal, fall back to thread heights; if those are still equal, fall back to thread spacing).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the best solution to me, complexity-wise.

An alternative would be to sort only one of the bags, then use binary search to try matching bolt to nut (removing the pair from the sorted list). Still `O(n log n)`, but the second part is optimized slightly, since we're removing each pair after the match, the worst case would be: `log n + log n-1 + log n-2 ... 1 = (n log n)/2`

Comment: @AlexD see bdares's answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Take two bags extra. Say left and right bags. Now take each nut and compare with each bolt. If the bolt is small place it in left bag, large then in right bag, fits then place it away. Now take the next nut, compare it with previously taken nut, if its smaller, then we need to check only those nuts in left bag, else to the ones in right bag. Continue in this fashion.